# Display post's main image that is in a different row using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

```
public function get_post_info(){
    $this->db->select('users.id as idautor,
        users.first_name, post.active, post.id, post.titulo,
        post.preco, post.user, post.data, post.img, post.conteudo');
    $this->db->from('post');
    $this->db->where('post.active',1);
    $this->db->where('post.isf',0);
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.id = post.user');
    $this->db->limit(8);
    $this->db->order_by('post.data','DESC');
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}

public function get_post_photo(){
    $this->db->select('users.id as idautor, users_pub_main_picture.url as url,
        users.first_name, post.active, post.id, post.titulo,
        post.preco, post.user, post.data, post.img, post.conteudo');
    $this->db->from('post');
    $this->db->where('post.active',1);
    $this->db->where('post.isf',0);
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.id = post.user');
    $this->db->join('users_pub_main_picture', 'users_pub_main_picture.pub_id = post.id');
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

I'm trying to get the post main image in codeigniter that is in different row and display in my view with post info but if there's 2 main images in image row codeigniter shows me duplicate post with same content and diffent images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public function get_post_info()
  {
    $this->db->select('users.id as idautor,
    users.first_name, post.active, post.id, post.titulo,
    post.preco, post.user, post.data, post.img as firstimage, post.conteudo');
    $this->db->from('post');
    $this->db->where('post.active',1);
    $this->db->where('post.isf',0);
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.id = post.user');
    $this->db->limit(8);
    $this->db->order_by('post.data','DESC');
    return $this->db->get()->result();
  }

 public function get_post_photo(){
    $this->db->select('users.id as idautor, users_pub_main_picture.url as url,
    users.first_name, post.active, post.id, post.titulo,
    post.preco, post.user, post.data, post.img as secondimage, post.conteudo');
    $this->db->from('post');
    $this->db->where('post.active',1);
    $this->db->where('post.isf',0);
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.id = post.user');
    $this->db->join('users_pub_main_picture', 'users_pub_main_picture.pub_id = post.id');
   return $this->db->get()->result();
 }
```